# Is this Vandermonde matrix with a block of zeros invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose you have an $N\times N$ matrix

$${\bf V} = \begin{pmatrix}
               1 & v_1 & v_1^2 &\dots&v_1^{L-1}&0&\dots&0\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
        1 & v_K & v_K^2 &\dots&v_K^{L-1}&0&\dots&0\\
        1 & v_{K+1} & v_{K+1}^2 &\dots&v_{K+1}^{L-1}&v_{K+1}^{L}&\dots&v_{K+1}^{N-1}\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\        
        1 & v_{N} & v_{N}^2 &\dots&v_{N}^{L-1}&v_{N-1}^{L}&\dots&v_{N}^{N-1}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

all $v_i$ are distinct and nonzero and $L>K$. Is such a Vandermonde-like matrix invertible?

My gut feeling tells me that this should be the case, but I have not been able to show this yet.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you already aware that when $L=K$ this is true unless one of $v_{K+1} , \dots , v_N$ are $0$?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I am aware the for the cases L=K and L=N this will be true. The real problem is showing that for K<L<N this is also true. I tried deriving the determinant by induction, but this approach becomes very cumbersome and I get stuck after eliminating the first K rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the simplest nontrivial case
$$\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a & 0\\
        1 & b & b^2\\
        1 & c & c^2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
and its determinant is
$$ab^2-ac^2+bc^2-cb^2$$
So it is singular iff
$$ab^2-ac^2+bc^2-cb^2 =0$$
$$a=\frac{cb^2-bc^2}{b^2-c^2} = \frac{cb}{b+c} \space or \space b^2=c^2$$
So it's not true. In fact, you can see the determinant is an affine function of $a$ by multicolinearity, so it has to have a root unless it is constant w.r.t. $a$. And the only way it can be constant w.r.t. $a$ is if the cofactor matrix corresponding to $a$ is singluar. I think this argument can be generalised to show any sized matrix will have exceptions, at least over $\mathbb{C}$.

Edit:

Ok, I've figured out the generalisation. Consider the top row. The determinant is then a degree $L-1$ polynomial of $v_1$, where the coefficients are given by the corresponding minor matrices. If this is not constant, then it has a root over $\mathbb{C}$. Hence there is a value of $v_1$ which makes it singular. If it is constant, that means all the minor matrices are $0$, so the determinant reduces to the smaller case
$$\det \begin{pmatrix}
               1 & v_1 & v_1^2 &\dots&v_1^{L-1}&0&\dots&0\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
        1 & v_K & v_K^2 &\dots&v_K^{L-1}&0&\dots&0\\
        1 & v_{K+1} & v_{K+1}^2 &\dots&v_{K+1}^{L-1}&v_{K+1}^{L}&\dots&v_{K+1}^{N-1}\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\        
        1 & v_{N} & v_{N}^2 &\dots&v_{N}^{L-1}&v_{N-1}^{L}&\dots&v_{N}^{N-1}\\
\end{pmatrix} = \det \begin{pmatrix}
        v_2 & v_2^2 &\dots&v_2^{L-1}&0&\dots&0\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
        v_K & v_K^2 &\dots&v_K^{L-1}&0&\dots&0\\
        v_{K+1} & v_{K+1}^2 &\dots&v_{K+1}^{L-1}&v_{K+1}^{L}&\dots&v_{K+1}^{N-1}\\
        \vdots & \vdots &\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\        
        v_{N} & v_{N}^2 &\dots&v_{N}^{L-1}&v_{N-1}^{L}&\dots&v_{N}^{N-1}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

If the $v_i$ are not $0$, we can just divide through by them all to get another matrix of the original form, but one dimension lower. We can keep doing this until there is only one row left, and then the minors are all minors of a regular Vandermonde matrix, so they can't be $0$. I'm still not sure about the wrinkle where one of the $v_i$ is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will be invertible based on the properties you described and the properties of [block matrix inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion). Noting that the $\textbf A$ and $\textbf D$ blocks (the upper left and lower right) matrices are Vandermonde - and thus invertible, that the whole matrix is invertible.

Comment: The blocks aren't square unless $K=L$.